# Error on empty project: "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the viewcontroller."

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller, crash

this error drives me crazy. I already spent hours on fixing this, unfortunately without success.
I tested my app in simulator, everything works fine. I'am testing it on my device (iphone 4 with ios 4.3.3) the app won't start.

So I tried creating a new project, build and go. And the end of the error now says instead of viewcontroller, key window.

To get further information about the error I setup an exeption breakpoint whicht breaks on throw and on all exeptions. Something interesting happend now: when I am launching the empty project on my iphone I get a warning: 
    `warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testing-cmaekkzgdqyseidlqkorvrdvvodg/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/OLDAPP.app/testing (file not found).` (The app which I am runnning is called testapp, not OLDAPP?! This was my last project!)

Some further errors now occure: 
    `Unknown class OLDAPPAppDelegate in Interface Builder file.` and `Unknown class RootViewController in Interface Builder file.`

I did clean all targets and made a clean build. Nothing changes…

I didn't change anything in IB, just edited the provisioning profile to run the app on my phone.

Help is very appreciated here :-) Hopefully someone can help me I would be really thankful.

The whole error message: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UICustomObject 0x18b410> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key window.'`

Comment: make sure all the required headers are included in all your files and also double check all property declarations to make sure they match

Answer (score 2):

This happens to me if I change the name of an outlet on the ViewController which was connected to something in the View in Interface Builder. For example, renaming 'labelFirstName' to 'lblFirstName' and forgetting to break and recreate the connection in IB.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll check that. It's really weired that the errormessage is referencing to OLDAPP.

Comment: That is almost certainly in your XIB then - the Application Delegate proxy object in the XIB has an incorrect class set, as does the view controller `RootViewController`.

Comment: But the new project turns out to be corrupt aswell. I've only changed the provisioning profile in order to run it on my iphone. And this project won't run, too.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem where there were no !'s in my XIB and no re-naming problems. To fix it, I just created a new XIB, copied in the view from the old XIB, and rewired all the connections.